# How to freeze weights of Basic RNN Cell in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

How to write a subclass method for BasicRNNCell in tensorflow, so that I could modify few weights of weight matrix and freeze them and train the model.

```
    basic_cell= tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=n_neurons)
    outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(basic_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
```

which has weights as kernal and bias. How can I now change few of the entries of these weights, freeze them and train the model?